# magento upgrade not listing latest available upgrade in connect manager

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade, ee-1.12, ee-1.14

I want to upgrade my magento version.

I am using **Magento Enterprise editon 1.12**

When I goto connect manager and use "Check for upgrade". No upgrade is listed. But **Magento 1.14 is latest version and it is not listed**.

Any reason on why didn't the available is not listed?

For community edition we can upgrade manually by downloading the latest files and inserting  our custom modules in that.

But in Enterprise Edition is there any way to do like that? Because Enterprise Edition is not open source